# Shortest Path Algorithm with some Restrictions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, dijkstra, shortest-path

I want to solve a variation of shortest path algorithm. I can't figure out how to deal with additional constraints.

> Few cities `(<=50)` are given along with two `(N * N)` matrices
>   denoting travel time between cities and toll between cities. Now given
>   a time `t` `(<10000)`, we have to choose a path to reach from city `0`
>   to city `N-1` such that toll cost is minimum and we complete travel
>   within given time `t`.

I know that with only one parameter such as only time, we can use shortest path algorithm such as `Bellman–Ford algorithm` or `Dijkstra's algorithm`. But how to modify it so to include two constraints? How can we formulate Dynamic Programming solution for the problem?

I am trying to solve it with DP + complete search. Am I in right direction, or are there better algorithms than these approach?

Comment: You can try this, create copies of the graph that represent time and toll between the cities .. then solve these graphs together, while in step i you will be able to minimize though all of these constraints

Comment: It seems ok to me, so your dp state is [time left][city]? The time left condition will help your program avoid the infinite loop, should be fine!

Comment: @PhamTrung Yes i thought about same approach, but was not sure if it was the best

Comment: I had that one time in an IA exam and the correct answer was to set a heuristic to combine both constraints. It might not be optimal thought. Take a look at the [A star algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). It might give you an idea

Comment: Try to google [shortest path with time constraint](https://www.google.com/search?&q=shortest+path+with+time+constraint). It will give you a bunch of papers on this subject. The problem is apparently NP hard.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use Dijkstra for this problem, first you need to create a graph of state, with each state 
 represents the **city and time left**. So between each state (city A, time t ) and state (city B , time t1), there can only be an edge if you can move from city A to city B with the given time is (t1 - t). And the value for each edges will be the toll. Solving this using standard Dijkstra is simple.